# Why does passing an enumerate function result to the dict constructor yield a type warning?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, enumerate

Consider these two `dict` declarations:

```
some_data = [4, 5, 6]
d1 = dict(enumerate(some_data))
d2 = dict((x, y) for x, y in enumerate(some_data))
```

The return value of `enumerate()` is an `enumerate object`, which I understand to be like a generator (if it isn't in fact an actual generator) which yields tuples of `int` and whatever the type of the elements of the iterable passed into `enumerate()` is.

So, `d1` and `d2` will end up with the same value after the above code and I would say the `d2` declaration is needlessly setting up another generator, pulling data from the `enumerate()` function result and yielding it without modification.

However, IDEs like PyCharm will generate a warning for the declaration of `d1`:

> "Unexpected type(s): (enumerate[int]) Possible types: (Mapping) (Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]])
>   Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations."

Why is this? Is this an oversight in the definition of `enumerate()`, which actually is an `Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]]` of sorts? After all it yields tuples of `[int, Any]` and it's just as iterable as the one created by a call of a generator?

Or am I missing some possible construction where the result of `enumerate()` cannot be dealt with by the `dict((Iterable))` constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known bug, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35037 (thumbs up near the title)